Pushout of manifolds is a manifold
Let $M_1$ and $M_2$ be two $n$-dimensional manifolds, and let $N$ be any manifold of dimension $(n-2)$ such that there exist maps $f_i:N \to M_i$ for $i=1,2$ that induce injective maps $(f_i)_*:\pi_1(N) \to \pi_1(M_i)$ on the level of the fundamental groups. I wish to know if the pushout of $M_1$ and $M_2$ along $N$ is an $n$-dimensional topological manifold.
More precisely, if $X =M_1 \sqcup M_2 / {\sim}$ where $f_1(x) \sim f_2(x)$ for all $x \in N$, then is $X$ a manifold of dimension $n$?
I think the answer is YES (but I don't have a proof): the situation seems to be similar to (but perhaps not the same as) that of taking the generalized connected sum of $M_1$ and $M_2$ along $N$.
But this situation also looks to me like taking a generalized wedge sum (I know the wedge sum of two manifolds need not be a manifold). So, if the answer is no in general, can someone please provide a counterexample for $n \ge 4$?
(A related question dealing with "smooth manifolds" and "smooth pushouts" is found here: When is a Topological pushout also a Smooth pushout? although in my question, there is no smooth structure on $M_i$ or $N$.)

What about the union of two $4$-dimensional hyperplanes in $\mathbf{R}^6$ meeting at a $2$-dimensional subspace? That is a pushout of the kind you asked about but doesn't seem like a manifold.

I'll think about it. But for instance, what happens when $M_i = T^4$ and $N = T^2$, where $T^i$ denotes the $i$-torus?

You can even consider a pair of 2-dim real vector spaces being glued at their origins as a minimal example, but this doesn't give you a ≥4-dim example

Go down some dimensions, and consider gluing a pair of 2-tori along a circle, eg sitting a hollow donut on top of another. That's certainly not a manifold, since near the circle, the space looks like the intersection of two planes in R^3 in a line.

I'm sorry but I don't understand why my question is being downvoted!

Nor I. It was an honest question, though perhaps people feel it is borderline as far as being on-topic goes (the question has 4 votes to close, 3 of which are to migrate it to math.SE)

@TopologyStudent: Not the downvoter, but it looks like you confidently asserted that the answer is yes without working out any explicit examples.  It’s not just that it sometimes isn’t a manifold, but it is literally never one.

It is not true that under the given conditions the pushout is a topological manifold. Consider for instance the pushout of $\mathbb{R}^2 \leftarrow \{0\} \to \mathbb{R}^2$, which is not a manifold since the origin doesn't have a neighbourhood that is like a piece of Euclidean space. As mentioned by SeanC in the comments, this could be bumped up in dimension to be starting with two copies of $\mathbb{R}^4$  being glued along a copy of $\mathbb{R}^2$ in each.
As far as the example with tori goes, here's an analogous example: consider gluing a pair of 2-tori along a circle, eg sitting a hollow donut on top of another. That's certainly not a manifold, since near the circle, the space looks like the intersection of two planes in $\mathbb{R}^3$ in a line. This should be able to be adapted to the example of gluing a pair of 4-tori along a 2-torus. It should look locally like the case of gluing the Euclidean spaces near the gluing, in any case.
